# WP7 - using Linq To SQL queries with DataServiceQuery<> filtering issue

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, azure

I'm communicating with Windows Azure through a service I created (hosted locally). It currently retrieves data from my word database successfully but I'm having trouble filtering it.

This is the code I use to retrieve records:

```
private void GetWords()
{
    DataServiceQuery<Word> query = (DataServiceQuery<Word>)(from g in dataEntity.Words select g);

    query.BeginExecute(ar =>
    {
        DataLoad(ar);
    }, query);
}

private void DataLoad(IAsyncResult result)
{
    DataServiceQuery<Word> query = result.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<Word>;
    wordData = query.EndExecute(result).ToList();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        PopulateList();
    });
}
```

I can successfully use:

```
DataServiceQuery<Word> query = (DataServiceQuery<Word>)(from g in dataEntity.Words where g.ID == 2 select g);
```

but I can't use:

```
DataServiceQuery<Word> query = (DataServiceQuery<Word>)(from g in dataEntity.Words where g.Name == "Plant" select g);
```

but I am unable to do string comparisons like 'g.Name == "Plant"'. So apparently it works with ints but not strings. The query runs but nothing is returned (it never actually finishes).

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Please post code where a comparison files.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. Could you explain in more detail please?

Comment: You said unable ... 'g.Name == "Plant"'.  Post that code line

Comment: Updated, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: for l2sql do you need to us g.Name.Equals("Plant") for string comparisons?

Comment: That solved it John, if you post it as an answer I'll mark this question as answered. Thank you!

Comment: This is more of a general comment and not to get on you case Cameron but it is amazing how many questions post the lines of code works but don't post the code that fails.